# Oracle select query based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

```
MESSAGE_ID  GROUP_ID    REV_NO

100     200     1
101     201     1
102     202     1
103     203     1
104     204     1
105     200     2
106     201     2
107     202     2
108     203     2
109     204     2
110     205     2
```

First I want to select all group ID's and their correpsponding lowest revision number. 
Then I want select first X message ID's (Controllable X input) with condition that it should contain all the revisions of of any selected group. For e.g if I select first 5 messages by rownum then all revisions of group_id 200 is not selected.

Hope I made it clear.

Comment: Edit your post and include the desired output.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  What does the first sentence have to do with the rest of the processing, for instance?